# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource for many-to-many mapping with extra column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I keep getting this error which has occurred when I have tried to map relation many-to-many with additional column (by implementing 2x one-to-many). I cannot make GUI without working backend where I have to have such difficult mapping.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
at com.example.s16207masjava11.S16207masjava11Application.main(S16207masjava11Application.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2296) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:975) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:802) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have tried to change something in the pom file according to some advice from StackOverflow but with no result.

My pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>s16207masjava11</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>s16207masjava11</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The "suspected classes":

```
package com.example.s16207masjava11.model;

import com.example.s16207masjava11.utilis.TypInstruktora;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.*;

public class Instruktor extends Pracownik {

    public Long getInstruktor_id() {
        return instruktor_id;
    }

    public void setInstruktor_id(Long instruktor_id) {
        this.instruktor_id = instruktor_id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long instruktor_id;

    @NotBlank
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TypInstruktora typInstruktora;


    private void wyslijZestawRobota(){
        if(typInstruktora == TypInstruktora.INSTRUCTOR_PROGRAMOWANIA_ROBOTOW){
            System.out.println("Wysylam robota");}
        else System.out.println("Ten instrutkor nie moze wyslac zestawu bo nie jest instruktorem 
       robotow");
    }

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "instruktorzy_wpisydodziennika",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "instruktor_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "wpis_id")
    )
    private Set<WpisDoDziennika> wpisy = new HashSet<>();

    public void addWpis(WpisDoDziennika wpis) {
        this.wpisy.add(wpis);
        wpis.getInstruktorzy().add(this);
    }

    public void removeWpis(WpisDoDziennika wpis) {
        this.wpisy.remove(wpis);
        wpis.getInstruktorzy().remove(this);
    }

    public Set<WpisDoDziennika> getWpis() {
        return this.wpisy;
    }

    public void setWpis(final Set<WpisDoDziennika> wpisy) {
        this.wpisy = wpisy;
    }

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "instruktorzy",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<InstruktorZajecia> instruktorZajecias = new ArrayList<>();

    public Instruktor() {
    }


    public void addZajecia(Zajecia zajecia) {
        InstruktorZajecia instruktorZajecia = new InstruktorZajecia(this, zajecia);
        instruktorZajecias.add(instruktorZajecia);
        zajecia.getInstruktorZajecia().add(instruktorZajecia);
    }

    public void removeZajecia(Zajecia zajecia) {
        for (Iterator<InstruktorZajecia> iterator = instruktorZajecias.iterator();
             iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            InstruktorZajecia instruktorZajecia = iterator.next();

            if (instruktorZajecia.getInstruktor().equals(this) &&
                    instruktorZajecia.getZajecia().equals(zajecia)) {
                iterator.remove();
                instruktorZajecia.getZajecia().getInstruktorZajecia().remove(instruktorZajecia);
                instruktorZajecia.setInstruktor(null);
                instruktorZajecia.setZajecia(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        Instruktor instruktor = (Instruktor) o;
        return Objects.equals(instruktor_id, instruktor.instruktor_id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(instruktor_id);
    }
}
```

Parent class (maybe something with id inheritance?):

```
package com.example.s16207masjava11.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Pracownik extends Osoba implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long pracownik_id;
    
    private String pesel;
    
    public Pracownik(String imie, String nazwisko, String pesel) {
        super(imie, nazwisko);
        this.pesel = pesel;
    }
    
    public Pracownik() {
    }
    
    public String getPesel() {
        return pesel;
    }
    
    public void setPesel(String pesel) {
        this.pesel = pesel;
    }
}

package com.example.s16207masjava11.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Pracownik extends Osoba implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long pracownik_id;

    private String pesel;

    public Pracownik(String imie, String nazwisko, String pesel) {
        super(imie, nazwisko);
        this.pesel = pesel;
    }

    public Pracownik() {
    }

    public String getPesel() {
        return pesel;
    }

    public void setPesel(String pesel) {
        this.pesel = pesel;
    }
}

package com.example.s16207masjava11.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class InstruktorZajeciaId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "instruktor_id")
    private Long instruktorId;

    @Column(name = "zajecia_id")
    private Long zajeciaId;

    public InstruktorZajeciaId() {}

    public InstruktorZajeciaId(
            Long instruktorId,
            Long zajeciaId) {
        this.instruktorId = instruktorId;
        this.zajeciaId = zajeciaId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        InstruktorZajeciaId that = (InstruktorZajeciaId) o;
        return Objects.equals(instruktorId, that.zajeciaId) &&
                Objects.equals(zajeciaId, that.instruktorId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(instruktorId, zajeciaId);
    }
}
package com.example.s16207masjava11.model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "zajecia")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowGetters = true)
public class Zajecia implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long zajecia_id;

    @NotBlank
    private Integer minLiczbaUczestnikow;

    public Long getZajecia_id() {
        return zajecia_id;
    }

    @NotBlank
    private Integer maksLiczbaUczestnikow;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date dataStartu;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date DataZakonczenia;

    @NotBlank
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Rodzaj rodzaj;

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "zajecia_oferty",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "zajecia_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "oferta_id")
    )
    private Set<Oferta> oferty = new HashSet<>();

    public Zajecia() {
    }

      public Zajecia(@NotBlank Integer minLiczbaUczestnikow, @NotBlank Integer 
      maksLiczbaUczestnikow, Date dataStartu, Date dataZakonczenia, @NotBlank Rodzaj rodzaj) {
        this.minLiczbaUczestnikow = minLiczbaUczestnikow;
        this.maksLiczbaUczestnikow = maksLiczbaUczestnikow;
        this.dataStartu = dataStartu;
        DataZakonczenia = dataZakonczenia;
        this.rodzaj = rodzaj;
    }


    public void addOferta(Oferta oferta) {
        this.oferty.add(oferta);
        oferta.getZajecias().add(this);
    }

    public void removeOferta(Oferta oferta) {
        this.oferty.remove(oferta);
        oferta.getZajecias().remove(this);
    }

    public Set<Oferta> getOferty() {
        return this.oferty;
    }

    public void setOferty(final Set<Oferta> oferty) {
        this.oferty = oferty;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "zajecia")
    private Set<Uczen> uczniowie = new HashSet<>();


    public Set<Uczen> getUczniowie() {
        return this.uczniowie;
    }

    public void setUczniowie(final Set<Uczen> uczniowie) {
        this.uczniowie = uczniowie;
    }


    public List<InstruktorZajecia> getInstruktorZajecia() {
        return instruktorZajecia;
    }

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "zajecia",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<InstruktorZajecia> instruktorZajecia = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Zajecia zajecia = (Zajecia) o;
        return Objects.equals(zajecia_id, zajecia.zajecia_id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(zajecia_id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have another @Id annotated property in your subclass. Removing @Id from subclass will fix this

Comment: Should I use id from parent class? It means pracownik_id instead of instruktor_id? Something like in this example?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309662/hibernate-refactor-id-field-to-superclass

Comment: You do not need Id in the child class , the id will be inherited from the parent class itself, if you still need an Id in child you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148864/hibernate-inheritance-with-different-primary-key

Comment: I thought I need subclass id for this purpose:     @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "instruktorzy_wpisydodziennika",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "instruktor_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "wpis_id")
    ) and for generation jointtableid:     @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(instruktorId, zajeciaId);
    }